# Count the consecutive letter in a string if the value 1 is there then it should be empty?

Tags: python

Suppose I am having the string "abbcccd" then it should show "ab2c3d"
Likewise I need to get the output?

Comment: I suggest you take a look at [dictionaries](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm). you can loop your string and keep occured characters as keys and their counts as values. You then can build your output from there

Comment: Strings have a `count()` function which you might find useful. Something like `[c + str(text.count(c)) for c in text]` will get you _almost_ to where you need to go.

Answer (score 0):

My try. Very simple for with a temporary string as reference during the loop.

```
s = 'abbcccd'
new = ''
temp = ''
for i, letter in enumerate(s):
    if i == 0:
        temp += letter
        continue
    if letter == temp[-1]:
        temp += letter
    elif letter != temp[-1]:
        new += temp[-1]
        if len(temp) > 1:
            new += str(len(temp))
            temp = letter

new += temp[-1]
if len(temp) > 1:
    new += str(len(temp))
```

as result you should get:

```
print (s)
>>>'ab2c3d'
```